# Why does Mallet LDA give poor results when then Gensim version doesn't?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, mallet

I'm working my way through LDA models for text analysis; I've heard that the Mallet implementation is the best. However, it seems to generate very poor results when I compare it with the Gensim version, so I think I may be doing something wrong. Can anyone explain the discrepancy?

```
import gensim
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim  


## Generate a toy corpus:

dog = list(np.repeat('dog', 500)) + list(np.repeat('cat', 20)) + list(np.repeat('bird', 20))
cat = list(np.repeat('dog', 20)) + list(np.repeat('cat', 500)) + list(np.repeat('bird', 20))
bird = list(np.repeat('dog', 20)) + list(np.repeat('cat', 20)) + list(np.repeat('bird', 500))

texts = [dog, cat, bird]

id2word = corpora.Dictionary(texts)

corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(i) for i in texts]

### Gensim model

lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus = corpus,
                                        id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=3, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)


vis = pyLDAvis.prepared_data_to_html(vis)

with open("LDA_output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(vis)
```

This gives the following plausible inference of topics:

[image: Gensim topic inference]

However, things work very differently for the Mallet implementation:

```
mallet_path = '/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'

ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=3, iterations=1000, workers = 4, id2word=id2word)

model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.malletmodel2ldamodel(ldamallet)

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(model, corpus, id2word)

vis = pyLDAvis.prepared_data_to_html(vis)

with open("LDA_output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(vis)
```

Here, there is very little difference between the topics that the model infers.

[image: Mallet version]

Now, it seems to me that I'm making an elementary blunder here--possibly by not specifying a relevant model parameter the correct way. However, I'm baffled as to what that might be. I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: This definitely works in non-Gensim Mallet -- the model is almost entirely converged to one-word-per-topic after four iterations. Using four threads for three documents is not a good idea, but doesn't seem to change results. This looks like a random initialization.

Comment: Great, thanks for the insight. Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: This [issue on github](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2069) could be related. It seems that the `malletmodel2ldamodel` method is causing the topics to become essentially indistinguishable. For some people this issue persists even after a fix has been presented.

Comment: This is a useful find, thank you. It seems so that the Mallet wrapper for Gensim is still on the fritz, as updating has done nothing. Most annoying!

Comment: For the record, I resolved this by uninstalling and reinstalling gensim. Mallet now works, though its results do not seem different from the gensim implementation––though that may well be my data.